# Integrate Yahoo Mail with website

Tags: php, yahoo-api, webmail

I want to integrate yahoo mail to my website (instead of using desktop clients like Outlook or Yahoo mail interface). Yes I am talking about creating my own interface (but using Yahoo API :) ). Googled it, but did not get any help. Can anyone give me some suggestions?

Comment: You might be able to access a Yahoo mailbox with IMAP or POP3 (see PHP [IMAP reference](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php). Last I heard one had to pay for this service though.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I will check it. Can we use webmails like squirrelmail for the same? I mean integrating with such webmails. Do you have any idea?

Comment: You should be able to use SquirrelMail to download mail from Yahoo via POP3. I found Roundcube to be better. I con't comment on integrating it, though.